# RPI python time.sleep causing false event detect on GPIO

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I've noticed on this little piece of code that I've put together to test If any EMI was affecting my inputs. Everytime I boot The first time I would run this script I get a false positve.

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

out1 = 17
out2 = 27
in1 = 26
in2 = 23

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(out1, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.setup(out2, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)

GPIO.setup(in1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(in2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


def read2(channel):
    print "GPIO 2"


def read20(channel):
    print "Button"


def read24(channel):
    print "Switch"


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print "start"

    sleep(1)
    print "waited"

    while True:
        print GPIO.input(out1)
        if GPIO.input(out1) == 0:
            print("LOW")
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(in1)
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(in2)

            GPIO.output(out1, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(out2, GPIO.LOW)

            print "one1"
            GPIO.add_event_detect(in1, GPIO.BOTH, callback=read2, bouncetime=300)
            GPIO.add_event_detect(in2, GPIO.BOTH, callback=read24, bouncetime=300)
            print "one2"

            print "pretime1"
            sleep(1)
            print "posttime1"

            print("HIGH")
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(in1)
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(in2)

            GPIO.output(out1, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(out2, GPIO.HIGH)

            GPIO.add_event_detect(in1, GPIO.BOTH, callback=read2, bouncetime=300)
            GPIO.add_event_detect(in2, GPIO.BOTH, callback=read24, bouncetime=300)

            print("HIGH2")
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(in1)
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(in2)

            GPIO.output(out1, GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(out2, GPIO.HIGH)

            print "one2"
            GPIO.add_event_detect(in1, GPIO.BOTH, callback=read2, bouncetime=300)
            GPIO.add_event_detect(in2, GPIO.BOTH, callback=read24, bouncetime=300)
            print "two2"

            print "pretime2"
            sleep(1)
            print "posttime2"
            print("LOW2")
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(in1)
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(in2)

            GPIO.output(out1, GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.output(out2, GPIO.LOW)

            GPIO.add_event_detect(in1, GPIO.BOTH, callback=read2, bouncetime=300)            # print "Turn on " , GPIO.input(24)
            GPIO.add_event_detect(in2, GPIO.BOTH, callback=read24, bouncetime=300)


        sleep(1)
```

I've tracked it down to *time.sleep* causing this to happen.

Has someone experienced this and/or could someone try and see if this would replicate on their setup.

If I comment the *time.sleep* on this piece of code, the false positives stops happening. but then, I got no delay, hahahaha

> ```
>         print "pretime1"
>         sleep(1)
>         print "posttime1"
> ```

Comment: Only use the `add_event_detect` function once, it should not be in the loop.

Comment: I'm adding and removing event_detect when as when using relay this cause EMI that will trigger events, so the only way around this is removing the event handler when switching on/of. How would you recomend me to implement this then?

Comment: what is `EMI` ?

Comment: Electromagnetic interference

Comment: What characteristics of the relay? I have worked with relays to handle bulbs or similar loads and I have not had problems since I place the relay a little out of the way. Never notice that kind of noise.

Comment: I have the relay just at the side of the RPi and cannot put it anywhere else, I tried putting it at about 10cm for testing pourposes but that didn't do anything anyway tried cap to mitigate this but that didn't do anything either. I'm using a relay module similar to this https://www.sainsmart.com/sainsmart-2-channel-5v-relay-module-for-arduino-raspberry-pi.html

Comment: @eyllanesc let chats